# escaping dollar sign in velocity

Tags: java, string, parameters, velocity

I have such a string in the velocity template file:

```
<a id="superurl_${getItemid()}" href="http://example.com?$param1=345&$param2=abf&param3=${par3}">link1</a>
```

That renders as

```
<a id="superurl_1288" href="http://example.com?$param1=345&$param2=abf&param3=${par3}">link1</a>
```

However, it should be rendered as

```
<a id="superurl_1288" href="http://example.com?$param1=345&$param2=abf&param3=zzz">link1</a>
```

How to modify the source so that `${par3}` rendered by its value and is not treated as a part of the string?

Comment: @Bathsheba Sorry, tried \$ and \\$ and $$. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `#[[ .. ]]#` to escape strings in Velocity. I think in your case the preceding $ may be conflicting with what goes after them. Try the following:

```
<a id="superurl_${getItemid()}" href="#[[http://example.com$param1=345&$param2=abf&param3=]]#${par3}">link1</a>
```

Also, make sure you actually pass a variable called "par3". (This is more likely to be the reason why it's not parsed?)

Answer (score 1):

You could set a variable for the dollar sign like this

```
#set ( $d = "$")
<a id="superurl_${d}{getItemid()}" href="http://example.com?$param1=345&$param2=abf&param3=${par3}">link1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not apply for the OP's specific example, but in general dollar signs only need to be escaped when they are followed by a (upper or lower case) letter. A dollar sign that is followed by any other character already stands for itself and does not require escaping. If there is some flexibility in the template, another simple solution is to insert a non-letter character (space, comma, underscore, ...) after the dollar sign.